# grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]

Tags: linux, shell, grep, sh

I'm trying to get list of all the databases on my server which I'll use to backup. Following is a snippet of code which I'm trying to print the list of databases but I get error. How to fix it? Adding double square brackets doesn't solve it.

I've looked into some similar questions but I can't figure out.

**grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]**

```
#!/bin/sh -

IFS='
        '
OLDPATH="$PATH"

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

MUSER=root
MPASS='sfdsfdf'

DBLIST=$(mysql -u${MUSER} -p${MPASS} -e 'show databases;' |  grep [:alphnum:] | grep -v Database)
for base in ${DBLIST}; do
    echo $base
done
```

Comment: You should show your script instead of pieces of it. Maybe related, ["grep: character class syntax is \[\[:space:\]\], not \[:space:\]" printed for every tcsh shell](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=649995). Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've update question with complete script.

Comment: I've read that redhat stuff, I'm on centOS. Not sure what to make out of that redhat thingy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line producing the error is:

```
DBLIST=$(mysql -u${MUSER} -p${MPASS} -e 'show databases;' |\
grep [:alphnum:] | grep -v Database)
```

When the first grep is run, it notices that there is a pair of brackets containing text between colons. It guesses that the user intended to put a character class inside a bracket expression and gives an example of the correct way to do this.

A bracket expression is written `[`**list of characters**`]`.

A character class is written: `[:`**class**`:]` for some value of class.

A character class (eg. `[:space:]`) is used by placing it **inside** a bracket expression, along with any other characters to be matched. So to match whitespace and the digits one through three, one could write: `[[:space:]123]`

Unfortunately, there is another error in the code, which is that there is no such character class as "alphnum". So correcting the bracketing doesn't help!

There is however a class: `[:alnum:]`

If this is the class intended, the first grep should be amended to:

```
grep [[:alnum:]]
```

Note that brackets are treated specially by the shell (they can expand into filenames) so it is safer to quote any occurrences:

```
grep '[[:alnum:]]'
```

Comment: Also important to note is that the error mentioning space can be misleading. This also is printed if the error is not [:space:] but [:alnum:]. Cause can be a missing `[` in a long sequence like `(\[[[:alnum:]]\])`.

Comment: The error that I encounter often, and then have to web search again to find, is simply that I forgot the outer square brackets:  The error message that grep issues is, IMO, confusing and misleading.  Instead of something like `grep '[:digit:]' ...`, I instead should express as `grep '[[:digit:]]' ...`  That is what I believe @jhnc is saying in the end of his answer.